# How to sort Enum and add to an array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, enums

I have an enum

```
    Customer("Customer"),
    BankName("Bank Name"),
    AccountNumber("Account Number"),
    Amount("Available Amount");
```

I have an array of ints, that contains the right order

```
private static int[] realOrder;
```

I have a method that sorts enum in the right order

```
public static void configureColumns(Column... newOrder)
    {
        realOrder = new int[values().length];
        for (Column column : values())
        {
            realOrder[column.ordinal()] = -1;
            boolean isFound = false;

            for (int i = 0; i < newOrder.length; i++)
            {
                if (column == newOrder[i])
                {
                    if (isFound)
                    {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Column '" + column.columnName + "' is already configured.");
                    }
                    realOrder[column.ordinal()] = i;
                    isFound = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And when i call that method like that

```
Column.configureColumns(Column.Amount, Column.AccountNumber, Column.BankName);
```

I want it to be printed

```
 * Available Amount
 * Account Number
 * Bank Name
```

I have a method, that returns a linked list according to the realOrder indexes

```
public static List<Column> getVisibleColumns()
    {
        List<Column> result = new LinkedList<>();

        int index;

        for(int i = 0; i < realOrder.length; i++)
        {
            if(realOrder[i]!=-1)
            {
                index = realOrder[i];
                result.add(index, Column.values()[index]);
           }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

But i get `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 0` because i should start from 0 to fill the array. If i sort the realOrder array from smallest to greatest, it works, but not in way it expected. How can i solve it?

Comment: You are doing something seriously weird and unnecessary. You are giving your own order to a method, why all the sorts etc.? I suggest changing the design completely, even adding another parameter to enum itself would be better, like `Customer("Customer", 2)`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want `getVisibleColumns()` to return the values exactly as they were given to `configureColumns()`, so why not just remember that?

```
public enum Column {
    Customer("Customer"),
    BankName("Bank Name"),
    AccountNumber("Account Number"),
    Amount("Available Amount");

    private static Column[] realOrder;
    private final String columnName;

    private Column(String columnName) {
        this.columnName = columnName;
    }

    public String getColumnName() {
        return this.columnName;
    }

    public static void configureColumns(Column... newOrder) {
        realOrder = newOrder.clone();
    }

    public static List<Column> getVisibleColumns() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(realOrder));
    }
}
```

If you also need a to know the order index of a particular `Column`, don't create a separate array to store that. Just add an extra field to the enum:

```
private int orderIndex = -1;
```

Then update the value when configuring:

```
public static void configureColumns(Column... newOrder) {
    realOrder = newOrder.clone();
    for (Column column : values())
        column.orderIndex = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < newOrder.length; i++)
        newOrder[i].orderIndex = i;
}
```